# IIS - system.badimageformatexception could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, iis, model-view-controller, 64-bit

I have MVC application. I need whatever it was in the x64. I have local iis with x64 OS. When I publish the project in Visual Studio I choose x64 configuration. When i set the value of “**Enable 32-bit Applications**” to **False** in IIS AppPool settings everything works well, but when i set the value of “**Enable 32-bit Applications**” to **True** i get an error. 
How can I publish x64 project to IIS server with “Enable 32-bit Applications” = True?

I still have a problem. I can not even run a standard initial application. here's a screencast (sorry that the IIS have russian interface): http://www.screencast.com/t/Kf0mpM9uFa

what am I doing wrong?

And sorry for my English. Bears, vodka, balalaika.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you working on your local machine same with your IIS?

Comment: Yes, but I also have the same error on a third-party hosting

Answer (score 3):

It’s because you are trying to run 32 bit dlls on a 64 bit system. Fix it in IIS manager by changing the advanced settings on you application pool to enable 32 bit applications. Or create a new app pool specifically for them.
original [artcle](https://www.cafe-encounter.net/p379/asp-net-iis7-system-badimageformatexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly)

Answer (score 0):

I got a simulation:

```
1. Project platform target x64 => Working in IIS.
2. IIS > enable 32bit application = > Working also.
```

My Idea is:

```
Kindly check framework of your application pool.
```

Comment: I have a Microsoft Visual c++ 86/64 runtime installed. Also with reditributable

Comment: I still have a problem. I can not even run a standard initial application. here's a screencast (sorry that the IIS have russian interface): https://www.screencast.com/t/Kf0mpM9uFa           what am I doing wrong?